# Unable to close modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have View opening in popup as shown below.

```
 $(function () {
        $('#lnkPremiumAllocationPlan').click(function () {
            var selPolicyId = $('#sltPolicyName option:selected').val();
            $.ajax({              

                url: '@Url.Action("GetPolicyPremiumAllocation", "Policy")',

                data: { policyID: selPolicyId },

                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.length >0) {                       

                        $("#modal_dialog").load(data);
                        $("#modal_dialog").dialog("open");
                    }                 
            }

            });
        });

        $("#modal_dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 600, width: 'auto',
            title: "Premium Allocation",
            buttons: {
                Cancel: function () {                   
                    $(this).dialog("close");                 

                }
            },
            modal: true
        });
    })
</script>
```

When I click on the Cancel button of the popup window, it does not close.

I have included the following files as well.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.min.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Unable to figure out what I am doing wrong. Please, help.

Comment: Does it close if content is not loaded with data. Please check

Comment: Yes,its getting closed if content is not loaded.

Comment: Apply the same logic in the page you are loading. This will solve your problem

Comment: The model_dialog div, i am binding to i.e. data is a url pointing to an action of a different controller which returns a different view. PremiumAllocationController->Index action->Which returns view PremiumAllocationDetails.cshtml.But my model div is defined in anotherView named PolicyView.cshtml from where i am making an ajax call to policyControllrer and on success of it i am loading model_dialog div with data url. I am not understanding,how can i put the logic in premiumallocationdetails.cshtml when my div is defined in policyview.cshtml.please help.

Comment: Are you returing partial view ? can uyou try returning a partial view and give it a try

Answer (score 1):

use $("#modal_dialog")   instead of $(this). this refers the current object only .

```
$("#modal_dialog").dialog({
   autoOpen: false,
    height: 600, width: 'auto',
    title: "Premium Allocation",
    buttons: {
        Cancel: function () {                   
            $("#modal_dialog").dialog("close"); 
        }
    },
    modal: true
});
```